# Помогите составить запрос MySQL

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер. Есть вот такой MySQL запрос:

```
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(image) as product_image,
                            p.id as product_id, p.title as product_title, p.description as product_description, p.description1 as product_description1,
                            p.text as product_text, p.keywords as product_keywords, p.price as product_price,
                            p.quantity as product_quantity, p.availability as product_availability, p.category as product_category,
                            p.cnc as product_cnc
                        FROM images i 
                        INNER JOIN products p ON (p.id = i.product_id) 
                        GROUP BY p.id HAVING product_availability = 1";
```

Как мне его усовершенствовать? Нужно добавить `ORDER BY DESC`. Куда его нужно вставить в запрос MYSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

структурка запроса:

```
SELECT 
   [DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW | ALL]
   select_expression,...
[FROM table_references]
 [WHERE where_definition]
 [GROUP BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | formula}]
 [HAVING where_definition]
 [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | formula} [ASC | DESC], ...]
```

взята из [Вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)).
Соответственно ORDER BY надо после GROUP BY